# How to use snopt libraries?

Tags: c++, interface, libraries, solver

My situation: I want to use the SNOPT-Solver in Python through pyomo's SolverFactory. I applied for getting the C/C++ libraries for the optimization solver SNOPT and got

libsnopt7.dylib 
libsnopt7_cpp.dylib.

After managing to put together a dummy executable which SolverFactory can call, it gives me following error message:

```
 IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:
'/var/folders/_d/vnct15hn3.9j8dhgqr6gjf3rw0000gn/T/tmpoSB0fh.pyomo.sol'
```

Nevertheless, there is a file with that name, only with a .nl suffix.

Does anyone know why this problem appears and how to solve it?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pyomo does not have a specialized or library-mode binding to SNOPT.  To use SNOPT from Pyomo, you will need a compiled executable called "`snopt`" that has been built against the ASL (AMPL Solver Library interface).  The ASL provides the interface that can read the `.nl` input file that Pyomo generates and will produce the `.sol` solution file that Pyomo expects.

You can get the source for the AMPL Solver Library interface, along with the wrapper for SNOPT through Netlib: http://www.netlib.org/ampl/solvers/.

Comment: I should maybe first say that I am on a Mac OS Sierra 10.12 system. I have downloaded the files in netlib's snopt directory to my Downloads-Folder and  removed the .txt extensions. Now I try to run ./configure, but it tells me :

Comment: Paul-MacBook-Pro:snopt User$ ls
configure  makefile.u
configurehere  makefile.vc
libsnopt7.dylib  snopt.lbc
libsnopt7_cpp.dylib snopt_.c
makefile.fu
Paul-MacBook-Pro:snopt User$ ./configure
-bash: ./configure: Permission denied
Paul-MacBook-Pro:snopt User$ sudo ./configure
Password:
sudo: ./configure: command not found
Paul-MacBook-Pro:snopt User$

Comment: First, you will need all of ASL (not just the snopt subdirectory).  The main `solvers` directory has the ASL source that you will need to be able to build the ASL library itself (that the SNOPT wrapper will need to link against).  The specific error you are seeing is because you didn't set the execute bit for the configure script after you downloaded it.  Either `chmod 755 configure*` or explicitly run the script through bash (`bash ./configure`).

Comment: So I did what you said and tried to build the snopt library after successfully building the amplsolver.a library (I hope that is what you meant by building the ASL Library itself), but I get an error that it cannot find the "getstub.h" header file, which is part of the solver superdirectory. So I copied the header file into the subdirectory and now get strange error messages like:

Comment: /getstub.h:48:27: error: unknown type name 'fint';
      did you mean 'int'?
 typedef fint Fileeq_func(fint*, char*, fint

Comment: Yes - that was probably too simple a fix.  You should follow the ASL build directions to the letter.  In particular, you should have the ASL solvers directory checked out, with the `snopt` subdirectory.  You should put the SNOPT source code in the `snopt/src` subdirectory.  Configure & build ASL first, then configure and build the `snopt` subdirectory.  If the compiler can't find the ASL headers, you can consider setting the environment variable `CFLAGS=-I/path/to/asl/solvers/dir` (and maybe `CXXFLAGS` as well).  If you get link errors, you may need to set `LDFLAGS`, too.